# Random string in infinite loop not working Python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7, infinite-loop

```
import random, string
text = "Something"
while True:
    randstr = text + "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(15))
    print(randstr)
```

Error at randstr
Please help

Comment: The number of brackets is **incorrect**. Remove the last one.

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: For me, it works... It prints endlessly random strings

Comment: expected indented block

Comment: it works now how did you edit my question?